# Parse JSON using Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse the 4chan board list using their json api.

The JSON I am trying to parse is here : http://a.4cdn.org/boards.json
I have verified the json and it seem valid.

I'm getting this error: `11-21 17:14:25.132: E/JSON Parser(32278): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Here is my code:

```
    package learn2crack.jsonparsing;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import learn2crack.jsonparsing.library.JSONParser;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://a.4cdn.org/boards.json";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_BOARDS = "boards";
private static final String TAG_BOARD = "board";
//private static final String TAG_WS_BOARD = "ws_board";
//private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

JSONArray user = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BOARDS);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String board = c.getString(TAG_BOARD);
        //String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        //String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

        //Importing TextView
        final TextView uboard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.board);


        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uboard.setText(board);



} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



}
```

}

Also here is my json parser I got from a tutorial:

```
    package learn2crack.jsonparsing.library;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE...` is not JSON

Comment: Could it be a compatibility issue with their api server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting some HTML code, not the json.

Change your `getJSONFromUrl()` method to something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
     return result.toString();
```

Comment: Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: ok so I added `catch(IOException e) {
      // ... handle errors ...
  } finally {
      // ... cleanup that will execute whether or not an error occurred ...
  }` and it's giving me this error

Comment: @SuicidalCookie i also try to get json data from localhost to be view in my android project, if you already solved your problem, could you please edit your code above, because i really need it for my current project. thank you before.